# CSS text-align on inline-block element

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have this structure:

```
<div class="father">
 This string is left-aligned
 <div class="divToCenter" style="display:inline-block;">
  //contains other divs.I used inline block for making this div as large as 
  //content ATTENTION: its width is not fixed! 
 </div>

</div>
```

How could I say :

**Let me have ONLY the class named "divToCenter" centered in "father" div.**

Thanks

Luca

Comment: Divs always stretch to accomodate their content, to the extent of their direct parent. No need for the `display:inline-block;`

Comment: father div is larger and its width is fixed so divToCenter tend to expand to its father's width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#left {
  float: left;
   background: #eee;
   width: 200px; /* width is optional */
}
#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="father">
     <div id="left">This string is left-aligned</div>
     <div id="content">
      <!-- contains other divs.I used inline block for making this div as large as content -->
     </div>
    </div>
```

Float the left aligned string or block to the left, then with `overflow:hidden` on the content it will automatically take up the remaining space and you can `text-align` it how you want.

Either that or convert the left content to an inline block too so it and content are side by side and you will be able to `text-align` each `inline-block` separately.

Comment: yeap thanks!I also kept the "wrap-left-aligned-content" solution as last resource..I thought should be a css selector to use my own structure without further modification but I guess I was wrong =)

Comment: I see the fiddle example you've now left in a comment on another answer and yes I think wrapping the left aligned would be the best answer - http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/ea47e/6/ - you can't target the "text node" part of the father div any other way

Answer (score 2):

```
div.divToCenter
{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: you need text inside the div to be centered like text align or you want the div itself to be centered? They are 2 different things!

Comment: I want the div centered..(btw the div is the actual size of its content..so content cant be aligned)

Comment: @JAA149 I also tried your tip before but it's not working..I added "!important" to make sure overriding is not happening ..If I apply the "text-align" property to father div I have all the text (including divToCenter) centered.. but I just want the div on center

Comment: to use margin:0 auto you will also need to define a width of the div.

Answer (score 1):

```
.father { text-align: center; }
.father div.divToCenter { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Update:

```
.father { text-align: left; }
.father div.divToCenter { width:Xpx; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: as I wrote above If I apply the "text-align" property to father div I have all the text (including divToCenter) centered.. but I just want the div on center..

Comment: I've updated my post, hoping to achieve your requirements, just set the width property of the inner div to make sure that auto margin is activated.

Comment: divToCenter width is dynamic..not fixed..thanks! I guess I'll use the "wrap left content" solution